# using custom x axis instead of date in the line chart

Tags: javascript, jqplot

this is probably very simple but i cant find the answer , i want to draw a line chart but i dont want horizontal labels to be dates

```
   var line1=[['2011', 10], ['2012', 50]];

  var plot1 = $.jqplot('Lchart{{$ctr}}', [line1], {
    title:'Default Date Axis',
    axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
    series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]  });
```

this works fine but as soon as i change the dates to some other label , it stops working ! 
basically i want to change

```
   var line1=[['2011', 10], ['2012', 50]];
```

to

```
   var line1=[[' some label ', 10], [' other label ', 50]];
```

but right now it has to be some sort of date to work other wise it wont show the chart

here is the document and examples  , it only uses date or no numbers at all in the x axis

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/cursor-highlighter.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using different type of AxisRenderer than DateAxisRenderer.
I.e. look into following link with an example of CategoryAxisRenderer

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php